# Can rebels attack each other?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Let's suppose there are two different rebel stacks in neighboring provinces.

**Can the two different stacks fight each other?**

If yes, can they cross the other province to go forward without fighting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebels do fight each other to siege down provinces.

Especially if they are "different" rebel type like one want to convert you to x religious while another want to insert a new Pretender on throne.

I can only think of one case where different rebel may not fight each other is that one of the rebel army is already engaged in fighting. That same army may end up fighting the second one if the fight finish too quick.

That is about all I know about rebels. That said there are some fringe edge cases that can be difficult to be sure such as rebel from different country crossing path.